# View OpenGL version *of* a remote machine via ssh

Tags: ssh, xorg, opengl, xauth

I have a remote machine accessible via SSH and I want to use `glxinfo` to check it's GL version.

I already tried the following:

- logging in with `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y`
- setting `DISPLAY=:0`
- setting `DISPLAY=hostname:0`

In every case I either get info about local machine (but my AMD card shows as being produced by VMWare for some reason, I haven't ever installed VMWare anywhere) or `MIT-INVALID-Cookie`

I tried googling about `xauth` but no luck. How to generate a valid cookie without physically logging in to the GUI shell?